# The same expectation means martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes

If a stochastic process has the same expectation value for all pisitive t, then is it a martingale?
I don’t know how to show it whether that is right.

Answer (score 2):

The Brownian motion $W_t$ is a martingale because for all $u>t$:
$$
W_t = E(W_u | \mathcal{F}_t), 
$$

However, the process $X_t$
$$X_t = 1_{\{a<t<b\}} (2 . 1_{\{W_a < 0\}} -1) $$ has 0 expectation but is not a martingale.

Comment: Hmm... Why 21? If you give more information , I'll very thanks for you.

Comment: I just added the dot between 2 and 1, this process takes value +1 or -1 between a and b, but it is not a martingale as it goes back to 0 for $t>b$